# List available fonts in linux

Tags: php, linux, encoding, fonts, character

I'm programming a custom bit of hardware (a media box) running a custom build of Linux (tangox 2.6.29.6-18-sigma #2 PREEMPT Tue Dec 20 14:00:43 UTC 2011 mips GNU/Linux) and need to find out what fonts are available on this system.

Globally, my task is to quiz a web service for some content and display it on the system (i.e. on the TV screen), but not all characters I receive from the "outside world" can be rendered via the font used by the media box. Fonts on the media box are outside of my control, as is the firmware - I have to get on with what I've got via the supported PHP API.

**Question 1**: How would I list all fonts available on the box, along with their supported character ranges? (We suspect that the font being used does not render some of the chars we need - so my issues can't be solved by just making sure everything is UTF8.)

I've tried:

```
xlsfonts (command not found)
/etc/X11/ (dir does not exist)
fc-list (command not found)
```

...none of the above helped.

I've located some fonts in:

```
ls -al /firmware/fonts

-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        42643 Dec 31  1969 verdana-108-subset.aaf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       236340 Dec 31  1969 verdana-25.aaf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       426097 Dec 31  1969 verdana-34.aaf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       696763 Dec 31  1969 verdana-44.aaf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root       834851 Dec 31  1969 verdana-48.aaf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         1539 Dec 31  1969 webdings-30.aaf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         5517 Dec 31  1969 webdings-38.aaf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         4509 Dec 31  1969 webdings-49.aaf
```

But I want to be sure that there are no other fonts hidden somewhere around the system and used by the firmware.

**Question 2**: Once I know the character range I can display in, is there a fool-proof way to strip out everything outside that range (I can do that), but simplify some of the fancy characters (e.g. accented e) into their English counter-parts? And last but not least - does anyone know of an existing PHP library that would do most of this for me?

P.S. Sorry if this question is a bit too n00bish - I'm not a Linux guru and don't have an intimate understanding of fonts/encodings.

Comment: There are various locations in GNU/Linux in which fonts can be kept. These locations are defined in /etc/fonts/fonts.conf; standard ones include /usr/share/fonts, /usr/local/share/fonts, and /home/<username>/.fonts (where <username> is your user name).
Are you able to check those places? That will only give you names though, probably not supported character ranges, etc.

Comment: /etc/fonts/ does not exist. It's a custom stripped-down version of Linux that I have no control over :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for Q1.

This

```
xlsfonts (command not found)
/etc/X11/ (dir does not exist)
fc-list (command not found)
```

doesn't work because `xorg-xserver` not installed. If it is planned then you have only console fonts on your box (surely you don't have `X11` fonts if you don't have `X11` (`xserver`) itself). To list console fonts use `ls -l /usr/share/consolefonts` (on most distributions).

Comment: `terminfo` , `udhsps` and `zoneinfo` are the only dirs in /usr/share

Comment: Do you have anything in `/etc/fonts`?

Comment: directory does not exist

Comment: The only thing I can think of in this situation is to do something like `sudo find / -name "*.aaf"` with all fonts extensions known to linux (not so much to do) or `sudo find / -name "*font*"`